# unable to compile "implements BroadcastReceiver" in Activity class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

unable to compile  "implements BroadcastReceiver" in Activity class

with Error :

```
Error:(12, 66) error: interface expected here
Error:(55, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

WifiController.java

```
public class WifiController extends AppCompatActivity implements BroadcastReceiver{
.....
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiController">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I want to know How utilize BroadCastReceiver in extended Activity class.

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` is an abstract class, not an interface.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand first that What is BroadcastReceivera and how it is implemented:

A broadcast receiver (short receiver) is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android runtime once this event happens.

The implementing class for a receiver **extends the BroadcastReceiver class**.

So you **cannot implement it**, It is a Class and not an Interface.

I would suggest create an inner class in your Activity Class to use Broadcast Receiver like this:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // assumes WordService is a registered service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
      }
    }
```

Read More [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)